# Python long running process is slowed

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a performance issue.

my script for checking existed files on NFS is dramatically slowed after few days of work.

for example in beginning it took 7 seconds for 1000 files, but now more than 40 seconds. I should not stop it right now and can not connect via debugger

I need check more than 24 million of records

```
    absent_files_detailed.addHandler(FileHandler("logs/absent-files-detailed.log"))
absent_files.addHandler(FileHandler("logs/absent-files.log"))

sql_logger.addHandler(FileHandler("logs/database-sql.log"))

# database configurations
datastorage_file_database = database_connector.DataConfig("host", "database", "user", "password")

LOG_MESSAGE_FREQUENCY = 1000
SELECT_BATCH_SIZE = 1000


def init():
    pass


def check():
    connection_factory = database_connector.Connection()
    database = connection_factory.open(datastorage_file_database)

    number_of_existing_items = 0
    index = None
    for index, record in enumerate(database_records(database, SELECT_BATCH_SIZE)):
        if int(index) % LOG_MESSAGE_FREQUENCY == 0:
            print cur_time() + " %s files processed" % index
        if not on_disk(record["path"]):
            number_of_existing_items += 1
            absent_files_detailed.warning(cur_time() + "item '%s' -> '%s' not exist on disk!",
                                          record["id"], record["path"])
            absent_files.warning(record["id"])
    print "END ->> %s items processed" % (index + 1)
    print str(number_of_existing_items) + " files not exist, but recorded in base."


pass


def database_records(database, fetch_size=1000):
    page = 0
    while True:
        # Every time  will be created new cursor, and old will be closed
        cursor = database.cursor()

        select_query = "SELECT file_absolute_path, id FROM item LIMIT " + str(SELECT_BATCH_SIZE) + " OFFSET " + str(
            page * SELECT_BATCH_SIZE)
        sql_logger.warning(cur_time() + select_query)

        cursor.execute(select_query)
        # increase page number
        page += 1
        results = cursor.fetchmany(fetch_size)
        if not results:
            cursor.close()
            break
        else:
            for record in results:
                yield dict(path=record[0], id=record[1])
            cursor.close()
    pass


def cur_time():
    return str(time.asctime()) + ": "
```

I recreate my cursor for database every time because has meet with problem  "database gone away".

**UPD**
Thanks for your reply guys.
There no memory issues (that says top command)

```
load averages:  0.18,  0.19,  0.19; up 59+19:32:39 09:21:25
120 processes: 119 sleeping, 1 on cpu
CPU states: 98.9% idle,  0.7% user,  0.5% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Kernel: 2356 ctxsw, 5 trap, 2219 intr, 1935 syscall
Memory: 64G phys mem, 33G free mem, 4096M total swap, 4096M free swap
```

@Sebastian it must be the my problem. Thanks, i will check it

Comment: Do you notice an increase in memory? Possibly less CPU utilization? You can track these every now and so often manually with top/htop.

Comment: [the limit/offset pagination may be ineffecitve; use row number/id -based pagination instead](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Comment: unrelated: showing the current time is builtin into `logging`. Don't insert it manually, configure the logging properly instead.